# Variable Declarations utilizing the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I am relatively new to Microsoft's TSQL, and I am trying to write a simple script that bases an IF statement on whether the summation of column TransactionTotal is greater than or less than the summation of RepairCost for the prior 7 days.

```
USE MyBusinessDatabase

DECLARE @TotalSales money
DECLARE @TotalServices money
DECLARE @WeekPast date

SELECT @WeekPast = DATEADD(day, -7, GetDate())
```

Now, the following Select/Where statements are where my problem is. The Select statements, which define my TotalSales and TotalServices variables, work fine until I add the Where statements. These LOOK right to me from what I've learned, but my IF statement ceases to work when I add them to the code.

```
SELECT @TotalSales = SUM(TransactionTotal) FROM Sales
WHERE TransactionDate <> NULL AND PaymentDate > @WeekPast

SELECT @TotalServices = SUM(PaymentTotal) FROM ServiceInvoices
WHERE PaymentDate <> NULL AND PaymentDate > @WeekPast

IF @TotalSales > @TotalServices
PRINT 'Total Sales > Total Services'

IF @TotalSales < @TotalServices
PRINT 'Total Sales < Total Services'

IF @TotalSales = @TotalServices
PRINT 'Total Sales = Total Services'
```

Thanks a LOT and let me know if I can help clarify anything! PS As a big fan of my data structures C/C++ classes I find this SQL database class horribly redundant and boring and I am glad to get rid of it!  I feel like I could enjoy it, but I really struggled with the class due to it being an afterthought with my algorithm and math courses eating my time.

Comment: any luck with my comments below ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `IS NOT NULL` rather than `<> NULL`.

SQL uses [three valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) (True / False/ Unknown)  and normal comparison operators yield `UNKNOWN` against `NULL`.

The `WHERE` clause needs to evaluate to true for a row to be returned from the query which can never happen with `UNKNOWN AND ...`

Comment: Bookmarked! Thank you sir for the help and that article's explanation is infinitely more helpful then my text.

Answer (score 2):

You want `IS NOT NULL` not `<>` so change that.

Your code ends up becoming:

```
SELECT @TotalSales = ISNULL(SUM(TransactionTotal), 0) FROM Sales
WHERE TransactionDate IS NOT NULL AND PaymentDate > @WeekPast

SELECT @TotalServices = ISNULL(SUM(PaymentTotal), 0) FROM ServiceInvoices
WHERE PaymentDate IS NOT NULL AND PaymentDate > @WeekPast

IF @TotalSales > @TotalServices
PRINT 'Total Sales > Total Services'

ELSE IF @TotalSales < @TotalServices
PRINT 'Total Sales < Total Services'

ELSE
PRINT 'Total Sales = Total Services'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the code is still failing to print anything by way of the IF statements...The system doesn't give any errors though.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to include my declaration of the @WeekPast variable. It is now included in my original post. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Using sample data this works for me.  One thing you can try instead of using print just do `IF @TotalSales > @TotalServes SELECT 'Hello World'`

Comment: @insomniac - Make sure you change `<>` to IS NOT NULL.  Try what I mentioned and just do a `SELECT 'Hello World` to see if you get a single record back.

Comment: If you still get no records it means your WHERE condition is not bringing any results, in addition, the values of TotalSales / TotalServices dont make sense or are null.  You may want to wrap the sum statement around `ISNULL` so that you have `SELECT @TotalServices = ISNULL(SUM(PaymentTotal), 0)...` that way if the value is null it is replaced with 0.

Comment: Also to see if you get any records back try the entire SQL Statement: `SELECT cols FROM ServiceInvoices
WHERE PaymentDate IS NOT NULL AND PaymentDate > @WeekPast`.  See if you get any results, if you don't that is exactly why you get no errors but also no print out of values.

Answer (score 0):

You might need "GO" statements after the queries?

Comment: Although not required, unless you are in a different db context.